# Does Trump ban on Iranian citizens prevent doing exchange studentship in the US?

Tags: usa

I'm hoping this is the right place to ask this question (otherwise please let me know so I move it to the right place). I'm Iranian and currently doing a PhD degree in Canada. I might need to do an exchange studentship in the US sometime soon. I had heard that Iranians citizens are exempt from the ban, but I'm wondering if that includes exchange students too (say, for a year of doing research). I'd appreciate if you provide references with your answers as well.

PS: my filed of study is in humanities, if that's relevant.

Comment: I think Expatriates is probably the right place (they deal with migration). Travel would be more about the visa and entry processes

Comment: @Machavity Not quite. Both Travel and Expatriates deal with visa and entry processes (and other things), but their distinguishing characteristic is _length of stay_. Travelers stay shorter times, and then return home. Expats stay longer times, up to permanently,

Comment: "I had heard that Iranians citizens are exempt from the ban" You mean that Iranian citizens are *subject* to the ban?